# Composite Server Templates tabs

Tags: templates, tabs, docusignapi

I am using the .NET Docusign Client from github and I am trying to det the API to send an envelope with multiple templates.

I have gotten to where I can send the envelope with multiple templates, but the tabs are not working right. I am taking all the tabs and making a global array of the tabs from all the needed templates and adding them to the signer. That works, but lets say I have two, two paged templates. When I open the link from my email to view the document The tabs from page 1 of both templates are on page 1 of the envelope. So there are tabs from template two on top of template one.

I am setting the template ID of the envelope and then setting up the composite template and adding a server template to that one with the second template listed there.

The document displays correctly, it's just all the tabs are overlaid.

When working with an envelope form a template, do I really have to move the tabs from the template over to the envelope? So far that is the only thing I have found to make them show up when it sends the envelope. I have to add the tabs to the template role recipient or it just shows a form with no fields on it.

Is that correct, or should I be doing it another way?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that the .NET client fully supports composite templates yet.  That said, it sounds like composite templates are definitely the way to go here.  You can specify multiple server- and inline-templates in a single call without "manually" moving the tabs over to your recipients.  Can you post a log of your API call?  That may help confirm what you are attempting.

Comment: As Jeff mentions the .NET client does not currently support Composite Templates, you can either wire up the raw API request for composite templates or you can modify an existing client function to get it to work.  In either case you need to be able to specify the request body JSON for the Composite Templates to work properly, which is why Jeff's recommendation of posting your existing JSON is a good one.

Comment: Ok, so, I ave gotten the composite templates working through the .NET client... Most of the problem was my lack of understanding about the REST API. Which begs the question, is there any better documentation? The docs on the DocuSign site leave much to be desired. I'm used to the .NET documentation which outlines every possible detail, in comparison to that the stuff on this API is lacking. The only thing I had to add to the client to get full (or at least the pretty extensive stuff I need) so, for the JSON, an inlineTemplate class, and a property in CompositeTemplate, after that it's golden!